# java.sql.SQLException: Column 'Max(category_id' not found

Tags: java, exception

Here is my code. It gives me an exception error says "java.sql.SQLException: Column 'Max(category_id' not found.". Please help. Thanks in advance.

enter code here

public class Category extends javax.swing.JFrame {

```
/**
 * Creates new form Category
 */
public Category() {
    initComponents();
    DisplayTable();
    autoID();
}


//Display Table
private void DisplayTable() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inventory?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC", "root", "ichigo197328");
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM category";
        PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}

public void autoID() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inventory?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC", "root", "ichigo197328");
        Statement s = conn.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT Max(category_id) from category");
        rs.next();

        rs.getString("Max(category_id)");

        if(rs.getString("Max(category_id") == null) {
            CategoryIDField.setText("C0001");
        }
        else {
            Long id = Long.parseLong(rs.getString("Max(category_id").substring(2, rs.getString("Max(category_id").length()));
            id++;
            CategoryIDField.setText("C0" + String.format("%03d", id ));
        }
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Logger.getLogger(Category.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    }
    catch(SQLException e) {
        Logger.getLogger(Category.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: (Try having a machine look for literals from error messages, here: for *'Max(category_id' not followed by ' )' *.)

Answer (score 2):

The column has a default name but it isn't the same as the function, the easiest option would be to change all

```
rs.getString("Max(category_id)");
```

to

```
rs.getString(1);
```

Alternatively, name the column in your query. Like,

```
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT Max(category_id) AS FRED from category");
```

then use

```
rs.getString("FRED");
```

for example. Finally, you should be using `getInt` or `getLong` if the column is of those types (which I suspect because you are taking the MAX).

Comment: hi. where you I apply this certain code? "rs.getString("FRED");" sorry I'm just new in learning java. Thank you for your help

Comment: where you currently have `rs.getString("Max(category_id)");` (but only after you change your query to name the column). `FRED` is just an example (and my cat).

Answer (score -1):

I think in the line

```
    if(rs.getString("Max(category_id") == null) {
        CategoryIDField.setText("C0001")
```

the quote should be after the round bracket.

Answer (score -1):

use alisa
select Max(category_id) as xxx from category

Comment: It would be better, if you take the exact code part from the OP, and tell him exactly where this line of code should be placed and a little explanation.